# How to read string from right PLSQL

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

In a table column, I have this value:

DV-2011-01-000004 (the data type is varchar2)

How can i get the part of the string '000004'? In t-sql they have this right() function but in PL SQL i cant'seem to find a function just like the right() in t-sql.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: In order that this question may help future developers: please edit your question to state exactly what your requirement was - do you want to get the string of characters after the last '-', or did you want to just get the rightmost 6 characters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
substr('DV-2011-01-000004', length('DV-2011-01-000004')-6 + 1 )
```

Comment: Ok let him decide, I'm generally for general solutions and not specific ones.

Comment: We can not know exactly what decision they need. May be my solution is general

Comment: Since OP did not specify how to recognize the last part of the string (fixed length or character) this answer is as "general" as the other.

Answer (score 2):

you can use:

```
 SUBSTR('DV-2011-01-000004', INSTR('DV-2011-01-000004', '-', -1) +1)
```

when using `INSTR` with negative start position he will find the last index of "-".
then `SUBSTR` will cut from this occurrence until the end (because I didn't supply Length)

Comment: in pl/sql double quotes used for identifiers, not for string